# Error when install npm

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I have an error when I try a 'npm install'

- Node v8.9.0
- npm v5.5.1

Image of the error log :

[image]

Nota Bene : by reason of contractual clause I can not make the name of the project visible.

Answer (score 0):

Before type npm install, you must ensure that you have the package.json file in the directory. If you do not have this file then you should create it by typing npm init.

Comment: I have package.json.

Comment: tell me more about the dependencies into the package.json